# TS - Reusable API request hook - type not assignable to type 'IUseApiHook'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, solid-js

#### What I am trying to do?

I want to create a function that can make any type of API request for a frontend application. Basically, I want to get fancy.

#### Problem?

I am in over my head and I need another eye to take a look at my broken approach.

Here is the error I get from the code below:

```
Type '<T>(options: TApiHookOptions) => { data: Accessor<T | null>; error: Accessor<Error | null>; loading: Accessor<boolean>; request: void; }' is not assignable to type 'IUseApiHook'.
  Call signature return types '{ data: Accessor<unknown>; error: Accessor<Error | null>; loading: Accessor<boolean>; request: void; }' and 'TApiHook<T>' are incompatible.
    The types of 'data' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'Accessor<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
        'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Accessor<unknown>'.ts(2322)
```

Code (everything is here):

```js
import { createEffect, createSignal } from "solid-js";
import axios from "axios";

export type TApiResponse<T> = {
  data: T;
  error: Error | null;
};

export type TApiHook<T> = {
  data: T | null;
  error: Error | null;
  loading: boolean;
  request: () => void;
};

export type TApiHookOptions = {
  url: string;
  method?: "get" | "post" | "put" | "delete";
  data?: any;
};

export interface IUseApiHook {
  <T>(options: TApiHookOptions): TApiHook<T>;
}

export const useApiHook: IUseApiHook = <T>(options: TApiHookOptions) => {
  const [data, setData] = createSignal<T | null>(null);
  const [error, setError] = createSignal<Error | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = createSignal(false);

  const request = createEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    axios({
      url: options.url,
      method: options.method || "get",
      data: options.data,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
        setError(null);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  });

  return {
    data,
    error,
    loading,
    request,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `solid-js` but looking at [the docs](https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest/api#createsignal) and types the first returned value is a function that returns the stateful value.

That means you want to do this:

```
  return {
    data: data(),
    error: error(),
    loading: loading(),
    request,
  };
```

But there is still a problem with `request`. You have it typed as a function, but `createEffect` returns `void`. I don't think you want [an effect](https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest/api#createeffect) here at all (an effect is a function run after any render in which the depedencies have changed). This is a callback (something you run when a user takes an action), not an effect. In plain react you would use `useCallback()` to memoize this function. But I guess `solid-js` would just [memoize](https://www.solidjs.com/docs/latest/api#creatememo) it?

```
  const request = createMemo(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    axios({
      url: options.url,
      method: options.method || "get",
      data: options.data,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
        setError(null);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, options);
```

Though I'm not 100% sure what `solid-js` would recommend here, or if the memoization is required (it's required in plain react if this function would be used as the dependencies to any other hook).

[Working Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=5#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMIoA25ARugNZwC+cAZlBCHAORSoacBQoSLFxw0PFDCQBRZsyQZs41FIDKwAOYA7CoxZsOAIkIRywACYBaAFaFDAbkHho8FAA9gEQvvZxD7zztHfiQ3YXgYAE8wJDgAFQBBMGBkQkgtYgAeOIA+OABeXH44OHNJFAAueMcSpCg2KCrpeug4AB84LXxKRwZg0PC4KJj4pOAACQgIWmy8wpxi0vKquPbO7vIauDqGppaoNa6exfIIFHNgLQ0qqinyVC0tngBHfCRCGCqACgBKAryAG4QCy9fphFxDaKxRLJSbTADyYBgngyBSKJXwUHIVQ+UEuGi2ICQMAAFhBzAB+KqGDTEwxrQyQD70jqM-AwFl+cxIe5SByLMowFBUuAoLSRUH8ELgkSXKRQZjoWIASQAqsQxnD6AsSrMvhAkSjCCtNVNaIjkRAMj8TbCzbNelKBhDmPgtBgUQQNXbpnqDZaMraJmaLUabaMfTNcuixFaPnAANqClDYYgwAAi5QAumjlJIkOptBRsocNjkvkdyD8tmg4-AEztoKnic0GjnCnm1JodORMq3Wh1K+XK9XFrWMvXTud8c2YAAZM4XK7tsQSLtF8hfRXkYijsd1uAvN7xwpEUgUah0L6-f4xkpphfTq5fGBQN6jkolAJeL46z8YrEqn9I0ADpMXITBFn-IlSXJIDDTjECYLJcx2lZWkOUg-8SmTeCA0IEDkywz8GB+KDPxA0kkC0a8eDSOMkD+fI8j-bC4DTTMhS+Oj0mIQjyg-Nj2JbfYKw2QT-1I8iShAtBJDQElr0bKAmJY6TPzTfsoC+ZSJJIsi2JA5hLgvSJr1Uu9sIfRd8S3Chdy2STBIYbAE2AuMsz3EoeBgTEtEs3Cli4n5iNqfYqmU35QrgKcl2uGKbOfELyKPd4sEWPp+D6IA)